# Python __init__(a,b,c,d) not recognizing "self" as argument

Tags: python, class, init

I'm making a silly little game to learn Python and I'm having an issue creating a goblin creature with **init**

here's the generic creature class constructor

```
class Creature(object):
    def __init__(self,str,dex,wis,n):
```

and here is the call to that:

```
goblin = Creature(randint(1,2),randint(1,2),(randint(1,2),"Goblin"))
```

and here is the error I'm getting

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)
```

What is also weird is that I create the Player creature in much the same way and yet no error

```
player = Player(str,dex,wis,name)
```

`Player` is a child class of `Creature`

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and prompt answers everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've given your third parameter as a tuple:

```
goblin = Creature(randint(1,2),randint(1,2),(randint(1,2),"Goblin"))
```

I'm presuming you wanted this separate, so just remove the parentheses:

```
goblin = Creature(randint(1,2),randint(1,2),randint(1,2),"Goblin")
```

The fifth parameter is `self`, which is automatically called.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `self` you have four params and passing three:

```
randint(1,2),
randint(1,2),
(randint(1,2),"Goblin")
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got parentheses around your last 2 args to the `Creature` constructor. That's being interpreted as a tuple (single arg) rather than 2 separate args.